# Solution for image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, to start off, I'm sure out in the internet there is a good tutorial about this, but I can't even manage to "write down" a possible title for the problem, and I apologise for that.

I like a responsive and simple makeup:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
    <a href="#"> <img src="/your/image/url.jpg"> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="/your/image/url2.jpg"> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="/your/image/url3.jpg"> </a>
    ......
</div>
```

My problem is: I have different aspect ratio images to show off all with the 3:2 aspect ratio.

An easy solution would be to insert the images as a background to the `a` element with CSS, set it to be centred contained and then, with a simple JS script define a height to be 75% of the `a` width. 
I used this solution before, but this time is not working for me: I need to dynamically insert the images with PHP.

How can I get a similar effect to the above explained CSS technique but with the images declared in the HTML?

UPDATE: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fF6GL/ - but I need the above makeup, this one would not work in that case

P.S. if possible, I would like a solution without using a JS library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got a solution that is working for me, a demo is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/fF6GL/3/

Essentially, I'm just adding the background image on the CSS directly on the HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="" style="background-image: url(/url/to/image1.jpg);"></a>
  <a href="" style="background-image: url(/url/to/image2.jpg);"></a>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
div {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;

    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For the height, I'm using a small clever trick here:

```
div a:before {
   content: "";
   padding-top: 75%;
   display: block;
}
```

This won't work on IE, but sincerely, I don't care.

Comment: It isn't to spec... you haven't used <img> :)

Very nicely done. Great work. Also, I like "This won't work on IE, but sincerely, I don't care." hehe

Comment: True, but what's important is to add the image via PHP, more than using the img tag itself :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can put those linked images into a list, this might work:

http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/

Comment: That's what I was meaning in the intro :P - I will try this solution right now and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: I tryied many times, maybe I'm doing something wrong, I triyed even this: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video - But both are stretching the content and not adapting it to be contained.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with just the code you're using for this gallery. Share that here please, and I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CpHXZ/10/ - May not be perfect because I had to do it all over again, I apologise for that.

Comment: The JSFiddle looks good. When you put a border around `li`, you see that all elements have the same size and maintain the image's original ratio. What is your problem?

Comment: I would like them to be contained within the div, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fF6GL/ -- But as explained, I need the images to be in the html, added via PHP

Comment: @Alberto Sorry mate, if you can't add another element around each image (<li> or <div> or <span>), you can't the look you want.

Note that if you're ok with using JS, you could use that to add the outer elements.